# How to change colours on Pandas plot.pie()

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling with colours on Pandas pie plot. A sample code will help to isolate my issue in the present contest.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.zeros(31)
b = np.zeros(69) + 1
A = np.concatenate(( a, b) )
np.random.shuffle(A)
pd.Series(A).value_counts().plot.pie( autopct = "%.2f%%" )
plt.show()
```

As you can see here [image]

the result is a pie plot with blue and green colours respectively. What I am looking for is something like

```
pd.Series(A).value_counts().plot.pie( autopct = "%.2f%%", colours = ['red', 'pink'] )
```

But it looks like there isn't anything so easy. Could you help me, please?

Comment: It's `colors`, not `colours`.

Comment: Voting to close as Caused by a Typo / Not Reproducible

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After fixing a small typo (no u in color), your example produces the expected result in pandas 0.23.0.

```
(
    pd
    .Series(A)
    .value_counts()
    .plot
    .pie(autopct="%.2f%%", colors=["red", "pink"])
)
```

[image]